# How can this conversion work in C?

Tags: c, string

I want the int value of the second char in a string;
NOT the ASCII value, just whatever is stored in there.

```
int strLen = 0;  
char str[] = { 'b', 3, 'd', 'e', 'f' };   

strLen = strLen | *(str + 1);    

/* this prints 3; it's OK */
printf("strLen => %d\r\n", strLen);
```

Now, this would get the value of the second char which is 3, but also the value of the 'b' which is 98, so I'd end up with something other than 3, which is what I want.

However, this works too and the result is still 3:

```
strLen = *(str + 1);

printf("strLen => %d\r\n", strLen);
```

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: This is not a CG question. Read the [FAQ](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/faq).

Comment: ok, where should I post it then? SO

Comment: Yes. I think it's more suited there.

Comment: Without intending to be mean, I would say that this question exposes some basic misunderstandings about how c works. DO you understand what the bitwise-or operator (`|`) does? And what in the world poses you to think that the second assignment to `strLen` will have anything to do with `str[0]` (hint if you are thinking about the size of the variables you are doing it wrong)? Migrating in any case.

Comment: @dmckee I do understand what the `|` does. You are right when you say "And what in the world poses you to think that the second assignment to `strLen` will have anything to do with str[0]". I just thought the three bytes on the left of the int would be filled with "something". That's why I used the `|` operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taking a guess at the core mis-understanding here I want to concentrate on a reduced portion of the code here:

```
int strLen = 0;  
char str[] = { 'b', 3, 'd', 'e', 'f' }; 
strLen = *(str + 1);
```

The last line is an assignment. The right-hand-side (`*(str + 1)`) has `char` type. The left-hand-side is an `int`. What the compiler when assigning a small integer type to a large one is simple express the *value* of the small typed expression in the larger type.

So the assignment is equivalent to

```
strLen = 3;
```

Comment: what value goes into the three bytes on the left of `strLen`? would those bytes from the left change at all with the assignment?

Comment: @camilin87 The extra bytes are set to zero. This is logical, as if you set strLen to 3 (=0x03) you would want strLen to be 3 (=0x00000003) afterwards.

Comment: @camilin87: The value read by `*(str + 1)` is a `char` value, which might be signed or unsigned, but it only reads one byte. The surrounding bytes in `str` are ignored. When it is converted to an `int`, the value is converted from a one-byte value to a 4-byte value (typically), preserving the value.  If `char` is a signed type, then it is converted by sign-extension (so negative values stay negative and positive stay positive); if `char` is unsigned, then it is converted by padding with zeroes in the more significant bytes (and what was positive before stays positive after conversion).

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler that was the answer I wanted. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Bit-wise or-ing something with zero give you the original result:

```
x | 0 == x
```

So given `strlen = 0`

```
strLen | *(str + 1) == *(str + 1)
```

Adding the bit-wire or does nothing, so both of your examples are exactly equivalent, so of course they produce the same result.  It's not clear why you put the bit-wise or in there at all in the first case any way, it serves no purpose.

In any case any de-reference of str (including any addition of it), since it is a char* will always result in a char - that is one character.  *(str) == 'b', *(str+1) == 3, *(str+2) == 'd', etc.  If you want to get more than two characters out of the array then just get two characters:

```
printf("%d %d\r\n", *str, *(str+1));
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a hard question to answer because it is difficult to work out what mental model you have of the situation.

> I want the int value of the second char in a string; NOT the ASCII value, just whatever is stored in there.

The value stored in the second char in a string is accessed via `str[1]` or `*(str + 1)` or possibly `*++str`.  The result is the value stored in the string.  In your sample string, the value is 3; this character is also known as <kbd>CONTROL-C</kbd>.  This is different from the value that would be stored there for the digit '3'; that would typically be stored as 51 (assuming a code page based on ISO 8859-1 or one of its close relatives that uses the same character code allocation as ASCII).

The `strLen = 0;` and then `strLen = strLen | *(str + 1);` achieve the same result as:

```
strLen = str[1];
strLen = *(str + 1);
```

In both cases, `strLen` now contains the value 3.

The printing statement then converts the integer value 3 into a string which contains:

```
strLen => 3
```

followed by a CR and an LF.  (The CR is unnecessary, even on a Windows machine.  However, that's a diversion from the issue at hand.)

These characters are then sent to the standard output.  Note that the value at position 10 in the output (counting from zero) is the same as `'3'`, typically 51, and distinct from the value `3` stored in the string.  Your format requested this conversion.  If you want to print the character, then you say so:

```
printf("strLen => %c\n", strLen);
```

This will print the <kbd>CONTROL-C</kbd> to the output; what that will look like depends on your terminal driver and terminal settings.